# C++11 const - Is my code thread-safe?

Tags: multithreading, c++11, thread-safety, constants

I have the following class:

```
class Object 
{
public:
  Object() {}

  const std::string& get_name() const
  {
    if(_name.empty()) {
      std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(_lock);

      // Check if its still empty. Some other thread might have gotten here first
      if(_name.empty()) {
        //Run expensive operation
        _name = get_object_name();
      }
    }

    return _name;
  }

private:
  std::string get_object_name(); // <- Expensive function

  mutable std::mutex  _lock;
  mutable std::string _name;
};
```

Due to the fact of `get_object_name` being an expensive function, I would like to do a sort of lazy initialization and only call it on the first time `get_name()` is called. If it is never called then I dont waste resources grabbing the name.

I am concerned about the first call to `_name.empty()`. Is my current code guaranteed to be thread-safe or would I need to move the lock to the top of the function?

I watched some of Herb Sutter's talks, in particular [this one](https://channel9.msdn.com/posts/C-and-Beyond-2012-Herb-Sutter-You-dont-know-blank-and-blank), where this slide comes up:

[http://i.imgur.com/Jz4luYe.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2yQUM.jpg)

which lead me to believe that a call to `empty()` is thread-safe. But my variable (`_name`) is `mutable`. Does that "const == thread-safe" rule still apply here?

`get_name()` is the only function that can modify `_name`, for that matter.

Comment: There's a name for that pattern:  [Double-checked locking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking).  It works in some environments, not in others.  When it doesn't work, the reasons are subtle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not thread-safe since you (read) access `_name` outside the `mutex`, which breaks synchronization.

A possible solution is to use the `std::call_once` mechanism offered by the standard library.

```
class Object
{
public:
  Object() {}

  const std::string& get_name() const
  {
    std::call_once(flag, [&] { _name = get_object_name(); });

    return _name;
  }

private:
  std::string get_object_name() const; // <- Expensive function

  mutable std::string _name;
  mutable std::once_flag flag;
};
```

This guarantees that `get_object_name()` is not called more than once. The first call will initialize the `string` and concurrent calls will block until the lambda has finished.
Synchronization is fully taken care of, which means that any thread that gets the reference to the `string` can safely read from it.

Comment: Yeah that's what I was afraid of. Your `call_once` solution is pretty cool though, I like it. I assume it has a small overhead (nothing that will slow my program down some orders of magnitude if I throw that inside a loop), am I right?

Comment: @Mark A possible implementation for `call_once` is the _double-checked locking pattern_. The overhead (after initialization) is probably the equivalent of an atomic load/acquire, which equals a regular load on `X86`

Comment: `std::call_once(flag, [&]{ _name=get_object_name(); })` would seem shorter and more to the point.  A method whose only purpose is to be called once and containing 1 line of code seems a bit much.  :0  A brief mention of what kind of things can go wrong in practice when you violate the requirements here could be good (in particular, the pointer-to-string could reach the CPU before the pointed-to contents reached this CPU without synchronization.)

Comment: @Yakk I like the lambda suggestion, changed it

Comment: TBH, it seems that the `get_object_name` only has one function, so changing it to `set_object_name` (setting `name_` directly) is even shorter.

Answer (score 0):

Starting C++11 `static` variables are initialized in a thread safe manner.
If the expensive operation of getting the name can be made `static` I think the following is better:

```
class Object
{
public:
    const std::string& get_name() const
    {
        static std::string name = expensive_get_name();
        return name;
    }
private:
    static std::string expensive_get_name()
    {
        return "Name";
    }
};
```

Comment: This causes all objects to have the _same_ name, which doesn't mesh with the fact that it's a `const` (i.e. non-static) method.

Comment: Yes as @MSalters said that would cause all object instances to have the same name. The first call to `get_name()` would initialize that static variable and it would be used for all other calls to the function, even for other objects.